# Android Eclipse Correct Export?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, export, sign

I'm using Eclipse-plugin to develop Android applications on mac.
I've got a project and I followed the steps in 'Android Tools > Export signed Application Package' successfully, but all I end up with is a blank-icon .apk.
Is it supposed to look like that? I've followed the instructions from what I can tell.

And when I transfer it to a phone, it won't execute. It's just reads "Can't use as a valid .apk-file". For the record, the application works just fine in the emulator.
Any help on this please?

Comment: what does `blank-icon`.apk mean?

Comment: I mean that the icon for the file is like a blank paper which isn't associated with any program.

Comment: why would you expect windows to know wtf to do with a .apk file? How did you "transfer it to the phone" and what did you do that you mean "it won't execute". You really need to tell us ALL the steps you tried. Not just "I transferred to phone, nothing worked"

Comment: I was just wondering if it's supposed to be blank after those steps. Not that it necessarily had to have any else. And I transferred it via a USB-cable and clicked on the application on phone to execute/install or whatever is supposed to happen, but just get the error message. I've never done this process before and what info I find on the net isn't explaining it sufficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I've solved the problem... somehow. it just started working for some reason.
I guess the application was signed and zip aligned as aimed for after all.

Answer (score 0):

did you check taht you have an icon file inside your drawables folder?

drawable
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-hdpi

should have it at least in drawable folder but chek every folder just in case the current icon defined un any of those folder is corrupted.

Comment: The project includes icon.png in the folders by default and I haven't changed that setup, so that part should work correctly. Also, the icons seem to work correctly in the emulator.